# Angular5 ng-bootstrap - how to use just the ngb-panel

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How can you render just a Panel outside of an accordion ?

This does not render anything...

```
 <ngb-panel title="Login">
  <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    Hello
  </ng-template>
 </ngb-panel>
```

But this does (with collapsable accordion behaviour - which I dont want...)

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
 <ngb-panel title="Login">
  <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    Hello
  </ng-template>
 </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: What behavior are you interested in? Could you use the [Collapse component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/api) instead?

Comment: ah - I was after the old bootstrap 3 Panel (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels) but it looks like its not in 4

Comment: According to [the Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/), the Panel component has been replaced by [the Card component](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/).

Comment: Yup - just read that!  If you want to answer ill accept it.  m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/), the [Panel component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#panels) has been replaced by [the Card component](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/), which is not included in ng-bootstrap because it is obtained simply by styling with CSS selectors.

For those who are interested in having a collapsible container outside of the Accordion, they can use ng-bootstrap's [Collapse component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples).